# How to remove additional values being shown in X-axis which are not part of dataframe for Matplotlib plots?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am in my initial days of learning python (2 months with no past coding experience)

I have a dataframe as follows -

```
|    | Vehicle class | Year | Base_Tot_Sec_Vol | Base_OFW_Volume |
|---:|--------------:|-----:|-----------------:|-----------------|
|  0 |            2W | 2018 |     7.107110e+07 |    0.000000e+00 |
|  1 |            2W | 2020 |     7.218810e+07 |    0.000000e+00 |
|  2 |            2W | 2030 |     7.524556e+07 |    0.000000e+00 |
|  3 |            BC | 2018 |     6.935553e+07 |    1.522439e+07 |
|  4 |            BC | 2020 |     5.570438e+07 |    1.222779e+07 |
|  5 |            BC | 2030 |     3.955456e+07 |    8.682708e+06 |
|  6 |            CV | 2018 |     4.480700e+08 |    9.835683e+07 |
|  7 |            CV | 2020 |     3.597294e+08 |    7.896498e+07 |
|  8 |            CV | 2030 |     2.820582e+08 |    6.191522e+07 |
|  9 |            PV | 2018 |     4.208246e+08 |    0.000000e+00 |
| 10 |            PV | 2020 |     4.315216e+08 |    0.000000e+00 |
| 11 |            PV | 2030 |     3.045124e+08 |    0.000000e+00 |
```

I wanted to plot a graph with year as x-axis and y-axis as Base_Tot_Sec_Vol.

When I run my code as below -

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib .pyplot as plt 
fig,axes = plt.subplots()
width = 0.35

axes.bar(df['Year'].unique(),df[df['Vehicle class'] == '2W']['Base_Tot_Sec_Vol'], width,label = '2W')

axes.legend(loc=0)

plt.show()
```

The output is shown as below -

[image]

**I am unable to understand why the 'Year' column which only contains 2018, 2020 and 2030 is showing additional values in the chart. I tried changing the Year column which is of dtype = int to dtype = category using df['Year'].astype('category') but it did not produce any change.**

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `string` instead:

```
df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype(str)

df[df['Vehicle class'] == '2W'].plot(x='Year', y='Base_Tot_Sec_Vol', kind='bar')
```